# Set tenant settings

Tags: c#, settings, multi-tenant, aspnetboilerplate

I am working on a multi-tenant application, and my application has a `Currency` setting.

```
public class MyAppSettingProvider : SettingProvider
{
    public override IEnumerable<SettingDefinition> GetSettingDefinitions(SettingDefinitionProviderContext context)
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new SettingDefinition(MyAppSettingDefinition.Currency, string.Empty, scopes: SettingScopes.Tenant, isVisibleToClients: true),
        };
    }
}

public static class MyAppSettingDefinition
{
    public const string Currency = "MyApp.UserManagement.Currency";
}
```

I have added it in `PreInitialize()` method like below.

```
Configuration.Settings.Providers.Add<MyAppSettingProvider>();
```

**My issue**:

Now, this setting only creates entry for default Tenant, and there are no entries for other tenants.

So, my questions are:

- **How can I set Tenant specific setting?**
- Is it going to be on tenant creation time? If yes, then can I use `MyAppSettingProvider` class again?
- **Is it ok if I remove default Tenant**? Because host does not have Tenant Id, and I have a fixed number of tenants where default is not required.

Guide me, **what will be best practice that also supports boilerplate architecture**..

Comment: my main issue was in seeders, where previous developer added static tenant Id of default tenant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I set Tenant Specific setting?

Inject `ISettingManager` and do:

```cs
_settingManager.ChangeSettingForTenantAsync(tenantId, MyAppSettingDefinition.Currency, "$");
```

> Is it going to be on tenant creation time? if yes, then can I use MyAppSettingProvider class again?

Settings are not created automatically. You can configure in [`Create`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/c410ac4c2eb0781e741567d62ec4f3bbb902dab0/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Application/MultiTenancy/TenantAppService.cs#L72) method of `TenantAppService`.
You can (but shouldn't have to) use `MyAppSettingProvider`. `ISettingManager` is what you'll want.

> Is it ok if I remove default Tenant? because host does not have Tenant Id, and I have fixed number of tenants where default is not required.

Yes. It's created by the template for convenience and demonstration.

> what will be best practice that also supports boilerplate architecture..

Read the documentation on [Setting Management](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Setting-Management#getting-setting-values).